# Pygtk3 Specify gtk3 Label/CellRenderer font

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject, pango

According to a pygtk2 doc on [faq.pygtk.org](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq04.001.htp) The way to change a font is by a definition like so:

```
...

label = gtk.Label("MyLabel")
label.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("sans 48"))
...
```

### What is the equivalent in pyGtk3?

I was looking to avoid the use of a gtk css definition. Though I would happily accept an answer that utilizes gtk's css support.

My target font is gnu unifont (`unifont medium`), in case that changes anything; This font is readily available in [tty](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html) format.

I've assumed at this point that applying a font to a label is similar to applying a font to a table cell, though an example of both would be ideal.

The latest pygtk3 docs don't appear to cover this topic whatsoever: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/label.html, and font is hardly mentioned accross the entirety of the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

It's basically the same:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango
label = Gtk.Label('MyLabel')
label.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Dejavu Sans Mono'))
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use Pango markup [1]:

```
label = Gtk.Label()
label.set_markup("<span font_desc='unifont medium'>%s</span>" % 'some text')
```

[1] https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html